# What are different ways to implement internet voice chat application in java?

Tags: java

I m trying to create a desktop application using swing in java, which allows users to voice and video chat. I want to know what are the various ways? (Like using xmpp jingle etc, jmf etc.) Where should I start?

Comment: thanx Alain without your help it wont be possible to implement it. wait i then we need a class to run that main...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/). It works on the desktop and I've heard pretty good things about it.

Comment: thanx for reply zack, i ll try kryonet.
i want to ask one question?
i have little idea abt this point me if i ll be wrong,
>> capture voice from one pc
>> compress it
>> detect the other(client)'s IP address
>> transmit those bytes to that ip address
>> collect the bytes reunite to form voice audio file or play that stream.
is there any other point m i missing???